# How to enable tag moderation using rules?

Tags: 7, nodes, taxonomy-terms, rules

I would like to create a rule where if a user adds a tag(taxonomy) which is not allowed (e.g. 'Sexy') the content which contains that tag is sent to be moderated to the site admin for approval before being published.
I am currently stuck on the data selector part as I do not know what to put there!

Comment: "How" does a user actually add such tags? Is it by editing a node (to which a new tag gets added)? Or via the Admin UI? Some other way?

Answer (score 1):

I think this module [Content Moderation](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_moderation) is help to create rules

> - Some selected group should first review those changes (based one a    specific revision marked for "approval). In the meantime others
>     should be able to edit and create new revisions (which are not part
>     of this approval process)
> - Later some group can approve that revision and make it the new    live-version
> - Every state change (review, approval..) should get logged in a    history. You always want to know, who reviewed / approved what, when
>     and what revisions
> - You want to have a different workflow, like some other states between    review and approve and live. You want to define your own
>     workflow.
> - You want to create ToDo list for you reviwer / approval teams

Comment: The project is unsupported - how do I download it?